# Passing the return value of a constructor as an argument

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

class Bar { };

class Foo {
    public:
    Foo(Bar&) { }
 };

int main()
{
   Foo bar(Bar());
}
```

What does Bar() return, and why does this code compile?

Comment: "Why does this compile?" Change `main` to `Foo bar((Bar()));` to see that the code with the behavior that you want to have doesn't compile :-)

Answer (score 1):

It actually doesn't matter what `Bar()` returns because it actually doesn't do anything! The statement

```
Foo bar(Bar());
```

is a function declaration, declaring the function `bar` which returns a `Foo` and takes a function taking no argument and return a `Bar` as argument. This kind of declaration is known as [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Assuming the statement were written as as

```
Foo bar{Bar()};
```

the expression `Bar()` would create a temporary object of type `Bar` by calling `Bar`'s default constructor. Of course, the code wouldn't compile because you can't bind the temporary produced by `Bar()` to a non-`const` lvalue reference which is what `Foo`'s constructor expects.

Comment: I adjusted the program with the line Foo bar {Bar()}; in visual studio 2014, and it compiled fine. Is this a fault with visual studio?